# Compare text file with mysql database value using spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

Compare Key value of text file with mysql database value using spring

Example

database - mysql

```
| key     | value   |
|---------|---------|
|dbname   | student |
|uname    | usename |
|password | root    |
```

text file contain - file.txt

```
dbname=student
uname=root
```

Need solution usin java spring

If value is match say all the value are matching.

If value does not match replace the value (uname diff in db and textfield so relpace value in textfile)
If value not found add new key value (password not fount in text fild so add in textfile)

Comment: So what is the question? Can you add what did you try?

Comment: Database key match in textfile compare value then value not match means replace db value int text file key example (DB contain( key|value)(uname    | usename ))(textfile contain (uname=root) so value not match replace db valu into tex fild (uname   =usename)

Comment: well.. i think you have a big deal to change your logic ... why you need to check from a text file to verify on data base ? isn't your database your reference ?

Comment: i want compare the detail  from textfile and db value for before excute the process